# Consistent background fetch in iOS7?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, fetch

I was just wondering if it was possible to consistently update the data for my app every 60 seconds.

I have the following code right now:

```
 NSTimeInterval testTime = 60.0;
[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:testTime];
```

However when testing on the simulator, the app initially grabs the data upon install, and then doesn't do anything else. My web searches tell me that iOS determines when to actually trigger background fetch.

That being said, is there anyway to consistently have background fetches occur for the user? Like say, for every 1 minute? My app's big selling point depends on the latest up to date information. I think it's possible, as apps like Gmail,twitter, SnapChat are always checking for new data...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this using background fetch. You can only force this behavior using push (silent or otherwise), sending a push message to each device once every period of time.

Allow me to say, this is a terrible design. Polling is a terrible design for mobile apps. You should implement **proper push notifications**, notifying the user of new content, and loading it in the background as the OS deems possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I know of this isn't the best design, but as a broke student who can't afford to implement a APNS Server at the moment, I figure this could work.

Comment: @p0ny What is the app trying to pull exactly? Perhaps you should still rethink your design.